# Matching cells from two excel Tabs and returning description from Tab1 to Tab2

Tags: microsoft-excel

Yellow cells need formulas to auto-populate

[image]
[image]

Comment: Adding to my question, can there be multiple conditions from Sheet1 that can be matched while auto-populating Sheet2 cells?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a easy way to do this. Simply paste below formula in yellow highlighted cell in Sheet2 and it works!

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$234,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$234,0))
```

P.S. I considered only 234 rows here but can be changed to include the entire column!)